# Dependency: libasound2 (>=1.0.16) required for sl-modem-daemon

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install a SmartLink modem on Ubuntu Trusty. I need to install [sl-modem-daemon](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/sl-modem-daemon) but I have no Internet access so I cannot use Ubuntu Software Center to download the dependencies.

I used my Windows machine to access the Internet and download the dependencies. However when installing sl-modem-daemon with dpkg I'm getting the following error:

```
Selecting previously unselected package sl-modem-daemon.
(Reading database ... 164466 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack sl-modem-daemon_2.9.11~20110321-9_i386.deb ...
Unpacking sl-modem-daemon (2.9.11~20110321-9) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sl-modem-daemon:
 sl-modem-daemon depends on libasound2 (>= 1.0.16).
 sl-modem-daemon depends on libc6 (>= 2.15).

dpkg: error processing package sl-modem-daemon (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sl-modem-daemon
```

I already have [libasound2 (1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libasound2) and libc6 (2.19.0).

the follwings are the output, when I run `dpkg -l` and `apt-cache policy` commands respectively:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  libasound2:amd 1.0.27.2-3ub amd64        shared library for ALSA applicati
ii  libc6:amd64    2.19-0ubuntu amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Shared


apt-cache policy libasound2 libc6
libasound2:
  Installed: 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7
  Candidate: 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.27.2-3ubuntu7 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libc6:
  Installed: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Candidate: 2.19-0ubuntu6.6
  Version table:
 *** 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: You need [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO). [Enable it](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO#Usage), and install the package using apt.

Comment: @Braiam: multiarch is already enable, otherwise the OP would have never been able to install a i386 package. And apt cannot be used, as apt requires either Internet access or a mirror.

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini I already got used to Ubuntu doing weird things about multiarch, that I was presuming he didn't have it enabled.

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to install the i386 version for sl-modem-daemon on a amd64 system.

In fact, in your `dpkg -i` output you have:

```
Preparing to unpack sl-modem-daemon_2.9.11~20110321-9_i386.deb ...
                                                      ^^^^
```

But `dpkg -l` says:

```
ii  libasound2:amd 1.0.27.2-3ub amd64        shared library for ALSA applicati
ii  libc6:amd64    2.19-0ubuntu amd64        Embedded GNU C Library: Shared
                                ^^^^^
```

In other words, the versions of your packages are correct, but they are using the wrong architecture.

sl-modem-daemon unfortunately comes only with the i386 version. Therefore, in order to install it, you should do one of the following:

- either install the i386 versions of the dependencies,
- or reinstall Ubuntu, this time choosing the 32-bit version.

Comment: Do I need to remove amd64 dependencies, or just install i386 dependencies alongside?

Comment: @razghandi: install them alongside. Never remove packages like `libc6`, because those are essential packages for the entire system.

Comment: Multiarch is always an option...

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get all the needed packages from the main Ubuntu repositories from [`http://packages.ubuntu.com`](http://packages.ubuntu.com). The package says it needs `libasound2 (>= 1.0.16)`, which I think means it needs versions  *newer* than `1.0.16` which is also available in the trusty repo.

Another way of doing it would be to run `apt-get install --print-uris sl-modem-daemon`<sup>**[1]**</sup> on the server, and downloading the needed files with the machine that has internet access, and then install the appropiate deb files. This will likely be better as it `sl-modem-daemon` dependencies' dependencies.

For example, it might give on a Ubuntu 14.04 machine:

```
'http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/restricted/s/sl-modem/sl-modem-daemon_2.9.11~20110321-9_i386.deb' sl-modem-daemon_2.9.11~20110321-9_i386.deb 513368 MD5Sum:e46c8d65bf15e284a187ef2fb46521e0
```

<sup>URL filename MD5sum</sup>

Once you have managed to get the needed deb files, you can install it with `dpkg -i /PATH/TO/FILE(S).deb` - you can also use `gedbi FILE` or the Software Center if they are installed.

<sup>**[1]**: this will likely only work if the machine has previously had access to the internet to update the package lists - the `print-uris` just tells it to print what was going to download instead of downloading it</sup>

Comment: The problem is I have libasound2 (1.0.27) already installed on my trusty ubuntu but sl-modem-daemon, which needs a libasound2 version newer than 1.0.16, is not satisfied yet!

Comment: It needs a 32bit version newer than 1.0.16... (see Andrea's answer). Does `sudo apt-get install --print-uris sl-modem-daemon` help?

Comment: No. I gave up installing the modem.